# Spring Cloud shared configuration for group of microservices

Tags: java, configuration, yaml, microservices, spring-cloud

Is it possible to share some properties for limited group of microservices? I mean I just want to declare common datasourse in one place for several microservices, which will use the same database

I try to implement it using gradle variables, which should consist all data related to db connection with profiles, but probably easier way to do it exists.

Thanks

Comment: Instead create a separate `jar` module and include the module as a dependency to all the services where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. You're looking for "Spring Cloud Config" server:

> Spring Cloud’s config server acts as a single source of configuration
>   data for all other services in a microservice-based application. It is
>   itself a microservice whose job is to obtain configuration data from a
>   Git repository and serve it via RESTful endpoints. All other services
>   can either consume the config server’s API directly or, if they’re
>   Spring applications, treat the configuration server as another
>   property source in Spring’s Environment abstraction.

You can find a nice reading along with examples [here](https://nofluffjuststuff.com/magazine/2016/06/cloud_native_spring_configuring_microservices).